# Массовое добавление макроса в word-файлы?

Tags: c++, ms-word, макросы, docx

Здравтсвуйте! У меня есть папка с файлами *.docx* и *код макроса*. Требуется написать программу (желательно на с++), которая добавит данный макрос во все файлы. При этом никаких графических представлений не дожно быть.

Возможно ли такое реализовать? Если да, то как?

Comment: Еще и чтоб выполнялся автоматически при запуске? :)

Comment: @Harry, нет! У меня другие цели :)

Comment: Подозреваю, что надо смотреть в сторону COMObject("Word.Application"), а уж с помощью какого языка это делать — вопрос второй.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо. Это мне помогло. Я сделал что хотел!

Comment: Ну так поделитесь :)

Comment: В самом деле, дайте ответ на свой вопрос, это будет интересно и другим.